# How to display chantier of a salarie in laravel vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, foreign-keys

I want to display a CHANTIER of a SALARIE, with vuejs and laravel, knowing that there is a relation between them hasMany belongsTo, but I can not, it gives me an error "TypeError: salarie.chantier is undefined", help me please and tell me where is the error,

```
<tr v-for="salarie in salaries" :id=" 'tr_'+salarie.id ">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-id=" salarie.id "></td>
    <td>@{{ salarie.nom }} @{{ salarie.prenom }}</td>
    <td>@{{salarie.matricule}}</td>
    <td>@{{salarie.chantier.chantier}}</td> <!--i have the erreur here-->
</tr>
```

Comment: i think you should do only `salarie.chantier`

Comment: The error did not appear, but nothing appears in the box <td>chantier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell Eloquent to return the relationship, so in your controller you need to have something like this:

```
return Salarie::with('chantier')->get();
```